# Resharper 9 - How to use Custom Pattern to retrieve hidden method by qualifier 'new'

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am using Resharper Ultimate 9.2 and try to use it to help our development team to comply with our coding guidelines. One point out of our guidelines is to avoid using the `new` inheritance qualifier and use `override` instead.

I managed to implement a Resharper custom pattern to highlight such cases and suggest a replacement as follow:

[image]

The problem with this implementation is that I get a method declaration highlighted also when a class implements an interface or gets a private method for instance.

I tried to use some regular expression to recognize a hiding method, but got quickly a problem with the return type in the method declaration:

```
(public|private|internal|protected)?\snew\s([a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]+)\s
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it? I have also a similar issue with directive that I would like to point out with a custom pattern, but it seems like Resharper does not support this.

```
#if...#endif
```

Comment: " avoid using the `new` inheritance qualifier and use `override` instead." seems an odd guideline, since they *mean different things*.

Comment: Your are right, "using override instead" shall be a suggestion, not the rule. Still, we do not want developers to hide methods by using 'new' and prefer virtual methods to be eventually overridden